# Why more than 500 versions are getting created even limit is set

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning, version-history

there is an issue where in a document library the default limit for number of versions for a document is 500 but its still creating more than 500 versions for a document. Did u guys see this issue before? please let me know.

Comment: Biggie, what are the versiong settings do you have for your library? 50 Major versions and no minor versions?

Comment: default 500 versions , see the screen shot [link](https://imgur.com/a/QJhlJoo)

Comment: Interesting. I don't see the option "No versioning" in my tenant. Are you sure you are using SharePoint Online?

Comment: Hmm, that is strange, because it is a document library in a communication site , ya it is sharepoint online , that is so strange, but the question is if you have the limit , why would more versions being created more than the limit, is there any option that blocks older version of files from being deleted while creating a retention policy at tenant level?

Comment: I would love to run a test tomorrow and create 500+ versions to see what happens in my tenant. Maybe it's a bug and 500 means "unlimited"? You can also create a ticket with Microsoft in parallel.

Comment: i posted the same question in reddit and see one of the guys response, For your sharepoint issue, I've faced a similar issue in the past where we had some files that were regularly updated by an azure webjob, a handful of small files ended up using up our entire site storage as all the old versions were being retained even though we set a limit. After some investigation it turned out there was a policy set at the tenant level that ensured all versions were retained. let me know ur thoughts.

Comment: Do you mean that when you create more than 500 major versions, SharePoint Online does not automatically delete very beginning created major versions?

Comment: yes , that is correct , very odd behaviour, it keeps on creating more major versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run an experiment with a fresh document library in a modern team site in SPO. And I could not replicate this behaviour.

**Default Library Versioning Settings**

- 500 major versions
- no minor versions
- Original document version number: 1.0

**Updated the document 501 times**

I have updated a freshly created word document 501 times. Thus, the last version number was 502.0

**Result**

Then I browsed the version history for the file. As a result, I could only see the 500 versions: 2.0 through 502.0. Version 1.0 was not availailable because it was outside the 500 range.

[image]

<s>So, you might want to create a ticket via the M365 Admin center.</s>

**Update. Retention Policy is the Reason**

Turns out SharePoint Retention policies prevent old document versions from being deleted.

When Retention Policy is enabled, this is what you will notice. No old versions are deleted until they are past the retention period:

[image]

Comment: hi denis, i posted this question in MS forum and i got this response, this might be it, thank you so much for your input and help. this is what they mentioned --> "It may be due to the Retention Policy as someone mentioned in your other post.

    For items that are subject to a retention policy (or an eDiscovery hold), the versioning limits for the document library are ignored until the retention period of the document is reached (or the eDiscovery hold is released). In this scenario, old versions are not automatically purged and users are prevented from deleting versions.
"

Comment: You are right! I've updated the answer with an experiment repeated with the retention policy applied to the site